# How do I save an HTML element(s) to a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to add another one of these on an image click:

```
<div class="roleoption">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Public/images/delete.png")" alt="delete" />
    @Html.DropDownList("role", DSS.WebUI.Helpers.CustomHelpers.SelectListItemsForRole(Model.ExistingRoles, role))
</div>
```

And here I'm trying to create a new `.roleoption` whenever the add image is clicked:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //A roundabout way to construct the DIV I need:
        var $roleOption = '<div class="roleoption"><img src="@Url.Content("~/Public/images/delete.png")" alt="delete" /></div>';
        var $selectList = '@Html.DropDownList("role", DSS.WebUI.Helpers.CustomHelpers.SelectListItemsForRole(Model.ExistingRoles, 1))';
        $($roleOption).append($selectList);


        $('img.add-role').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().append($roleOption);
        });
    });
</script>
```

The MVC3 code you see up there, generates the following script on View render:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $roleOption = '<div class="roleoption"><img src="/Public/images/delete.png" alt="delete" /></div>';
        var $selectList = '<select id="role" name="role"><option selected="selected" value="1">Anonimo</option>
<option value="2">Registrado</option>
<option value="3">Tecnico</option>
<option value="4">Empresario</option>
<option value="5">Editor</option>
<option value="6">Financias</option>
<option value="7">Administrador</option>
</select>';
        $($roleOption).append($selectList);
        $('img.add-role').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().append($roleOption);
        });
    });

</script>
```

I get the following error:

> Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0
>   [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]

How can I make this work and how can I clean up this code?

I think the issue lies in the fact that my HTML helper return the select element as multilines, how can I workaround this fact?

Edit:

If I do:

```
var $selectList = $(' @Html.DropDownList("role", DSS.WebUI.Helpers.CustomHelpers.SelectListItemsForRole(Model.ExistingRoles, 1)) ');
```

I get:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $roleOption = '<div class="roleoption"><img src="/Public/images/delete.png" alt="delete" /></div>';
        var $selectList = $(' <select id="role" name="role"><option selected="selected" value="1">Anonimo</option>
<option value="2">Registrado</option>
<option value="3">Tecnico</option>
<option value="4">Empresario</option>
<option value="5">Editor</option>
<option value="6">Financias</option>
<option value="7">Administrador</option>
</select> ');
        $($roleOption).append($selectList);

        $('img.add-role').click(function() {
            $(this).parent().append($roleOption);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct that the error is due to the line breaks returned by the server-side code because the resulting JavaScript is invalid since you can't have line breaks in a string literal like that. You need to remove those line breaks on the server-side. I'm not sure of the exact syntax, but something like this:

```
var $selectList = '@Html.DropDownList("role", DSS.WebUI.Helpers.CustomHelpers.SelectListItemsForRole(Model.ExistingRoles, 1)).Replace("\n","")';
```

You may need to chain an extra `.Replace("\r","")` after the first replace. And you may need a `.ToString()` *before* the first `.Replace()`.

Beyond that though I think you have another problem because I suspect the following code isn't doing quite what you think it is:

```
$($roleOption).append($selectList);
$('img.add-role').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().append($roleOption);
});
```

The `$roleOption` and `$selectList` variables are both strings. When you do this:

```
$($roleOption).append($selectList);
```

jQuery will parse `$roleOption` to create a new jQuery object and then append the `$selectList` to that object, but you don't actually save a reference to the resulting object in a variable at all. So then within the `.click` handler when you append `$roleOption` it is just appending the original string. Probably you meant to do this:

```
$roleOption = $($roleOption).append($selectList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to wrap `$()` around the html and it will be parsed by jQuery.  I don't know exactly how MVC3 plays with this, but I would try:

```
var $selectList = $(' @Html.DropDownList("role", DSS.WebUI.Helpers.CustomHelpers.SelectListItemsForRole(Model.ExistingRoles, 1)).Replace("\n", "") ');
```

Edit:  Due to the fact that `@Html.DropDownList()` returns multiple lines, you would need to remove them by adding `.Replace("\n", "")`.  I think.

Comment: `could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMDocumentFragment.appendChild]` - Do you have a link to the documentation on that specific jQuery fuction. Maybe I have to wrap my HTML output with strings.

Comment: Ok, added the quotes inside the jQuery wrapper and the issue still stands. I highly suspect it's the multiline HTML that's generate that confuses the javascript engine. What can I do to workaround this? Any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: What is the output of the MVC3 render with my latest edit (single quotes)?

Comment: Argh, I forgot that javascript doesn't play nice with multi-line strings... hmm.

Comment: Can you do a `.Replace("\n", "")` on your MVC code as I did in my edit?